# Building a box with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to build a box with CSS3. The dimension shall be given in percentage. How do I calculate the right values for the position and dimension for the parts of the box that have a skew of 45deg. Somehow the parts do not fit together, the parts overlap, are to short or too long.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqpZ7/1/)

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.wrap {
    margin:100px;
    width: 400px;
    height:1600px;
    position: relative;
}
.back {
    position: absolute;
    left:0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.back:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    left:-24%;
    top: 3%;
    background:black;
    transform: skew(0, -45deg);
}
.back:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:6%;
    left:-12%;
    top: 0%;
    background:rgba(111, 111, 255, 0.6);
    transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using CSS3 3D transform to construct your box, and using the `perspective` property to adjust how the 3D image should look like? You can see how MDN does it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective. Also, Chris Coyier has a pretty wicked write up on this, too http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

Comment: I agree with @Terry, but here what you wanted just in case... http://jsfiddle.net/ZqpZ7/2/

Comment: @PedroEstrada That should be an answer! :)

Comment: @PedroEstrada as you can see the parts do not fit correctly, 1-2px do overlap

Comment: http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/
One of the best resources i have found on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqpZ7/7/

```
.back:before{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    left:-25%;
    top: 2%;
    margin-top:18px;
    background:black;
    -webkit-transform: skew(0,-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0,-45deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0,-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0,-45deg);
    transform: skew(0,-45deg);
}

.back:after{
    z-index:10;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width:101%;
    height:6%;
    left:-12%;
    top: 0%;
    background:rgba(111,111,255,0.6);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
    transform: skew(-45deg);
}
.right{
    position: absolute;
    right:0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.right:before{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    right:0%;
    top: 3%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background:black;
    -webkit-transform: skew(0,-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0,-45deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0,-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0,-45deg);
    transform: skew(0,-45deg);
}
```

Comment: I only build 3 parts of the box, because it was enough to see that the part do not fit correctly. There is always 1-2 pixel missing or overlapping. The top of your box does not fit and the other party have the same mistakes like mine. It does not fit correctly...